# Compare 2D arrays with an array, and replacing matching elements

Tags: java, arrays, multidimensional-array

Basically, I am trying to compare 2D arrays with an array, and if an element matches in single array with 2D array, the 2D array replaces the value of single array. I'll give an example:

So, there are two 2D arrays:

```
arrayOne = [[livesAt, fname, city], [worksAt, fname, company]]
arrayTwo = [[livesAt, x, y], [worksAt, x, z]]
```

And a single array:

```
findOut = [x,y,z]
```

The aim is arrayOne replaces everything in arrayTwo, and find out the elements in findOut array by comparing with arrayTwo.

**Edit:** The value of "x" reads the values of the location in the arrays... which is fname. So, the value of  "x" has to be the **same** from the first row and second row (fname).

The answer should be:

```
arrayOne = [[livesAt, fname, city], [worksAt, fname, company]]
arrayTwo = [[livesAt, fname, city], [worksAt, fname, company]]
findOut = [fname,city,company]
```

I have attempted this in my code, like this:

```
for (int i = 0; i < arrayOne.length;i++ ) {
        for (int j = 0; j < arrayTwo.length; j++){
            for(int x = 0; x < findOut.length;x++){
                if(arrayTwo[i][j].equals(findOut[x])) {
                    arrayTwo[i] = arrayOne[i];
                    arrayTwo[j] = arrayOne[j];
                    findOut[x] = arrayOne[i][j];

                    System.out.println("Match found");
                }else{
                    System.out.println("Not found");
                }
        }
    }
}
```

Most of it works except the findOut array only replaces the first element 'x' and not the others.

> [fname, y, z]

And during the loop, it prints:

```
Not found
Not found
Not found
Match found
Not found
Not found
Not found
Not found
Not found
Match found
Not found
Not found
```

I strongly feel there is a problem with my loop. Can anyone give me any pointers or suggestions on how to solve this? I have been trying to figure this out, but only made small progress.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is; when you give your for loop condition with `i < arrayTwo.length`, it just iterates for only 2 times because `arrayTwo` has only 2 arrays in it. But you want to traverse those 2 array's all elements and you are not providing a loop for it.

Also, when you find a match, you both change `arrayTwo` and `findOut` array values dynamically and that will cause a mismatch when you try to find same elements' match. So it works wrong. You need to store previous values of `findOut` in order to compare those values(`x, y, z`) again in case of duplicate values(i.e you have two `x` values in `arrayTwo` and at first match, you change `x` with `fname`, so there won't be any second match). You can do it like this:

```
String[] temp = findOut.clone();

for (int i = 0; i < arrayTwo.length; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < arrayTwo[i].length; j++) {
            for (int x = 0; x < temp.length; x++) {
                if (arrayTwo[i][j].equals(temp[x])) {
                    arrayTwo[i][j] = arrayOne[i][j];
                    findOut[x] = arrayTwo[i][j];

                    System.out.println("Match found");
                }
                else {
                System.out.println("Not found");
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

And the arrays will change as you expected:

```
arrayOne = [[livesAt, fname, city], [worksAt, fname, company]]
arrayTwo = [[livesAt, fname, city], [worksAt, fname, company]]
findOut = [fname,city,company]
```

Comment: Very clear. Thanks a lot. I guess it's not necessary to loop through arrayOne? I created a loop for that and still gives same output.

Comment: @user3080993 No problem, hope you accept it as a solution :) I didn't traverse `arrayOne` because you are not trying to compare an element from it with another string, so why we should loop through it? :) Btw, I assume that `arrayOne` and `arrayTwo` will have same amount of arrays which have same amount of strings in it.

Comment: Okay, yeah thats true, most important is comparing them. yeah I used it as a solution, but I will have to add other things to it. If I had my previous account back, I can +1 on answer useful

Answer (score 0):

```
  if(arrayTwo[i][j].equals(findOut[x])) {   
       arrayTwo[i] = arrayOne[i];     // Here you are replacing the entire element. What you need to do is only replace that particular value using [i][j]
       arrayTwo[j] = arrayOne[j];
       findOut[x] = arrayOne[i][j];
  }
```

What you need to do is,

```
  if(arrayTwo[i][j].equals(findOut[x])) {   
       arrayTwo[i][j] = arrayOne[i][j];          
       findOut[x] = arrayOne[i][j];
  }
```

Also, .length of a 2-dimensional array would give you the number of arrays in it. Not the number of elements in each of the array in it. So in order to fetch the proper length, you have to fetch an array within it and find its length.

```
  for (int i = 0; i < arrayOne.length; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < arrayTwo[i].length; j++) {
            for (int x = 0; x < findOut.length; x++) {
                if (arrayTwo[i][j].equals(findOut[x])) {                        
                    findOut[x] = arrayOne[i][j];
                    System.out.println("Match found");
                } else {
                    System.out.println("Not found");
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Hey, thanks a lot. did not know that I was not fetching the length of the 2D array correctly. thanks for pointing the mistakes in my code, I shall not make the same mistakes again.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think these 2 lines are correct:

```
arrayTwo[i] = arrayOne[i];
arrayTwo[j] = arrayOne[j];
```

Because `arrayTwo[i] = arrayOne[i]` will cause the if statement to always be true:
`if(arrayTwo[i][j].equals(findOut[x]))`

Shouldn't it be  `arrayTwo[i][j] = arrayOne[i][j];`

Comment: I tried that and surprisingly, it works differently and only replaces one element in arrayTwo: [[livesAt, gender, y], [worksAt, x, z]]

Answer (score 0):

Your question is not clear

What happens if the arrays look like this?

```
arrayOne = [[livesAt, fname, city], [worksAt, gname, company]]
arrayTwo = [[livesAt, x, y], [worksAt, x, z]]
findOut = [x,y,z]
```

will the result be this

```
arrayOne = [[livesAt, fname, city], [worksAt, gname, company]]
arrayTwo = [[livesAt, fname, city], [worksAt, gname, company]]
findOut = [fname,city,company]
```

or this

```
arrayOne = [[livesAt, fname, city], [worksAt, gname, company]]
arrayTwo = [[livesAt, fname, city], [worksAt, gname, company]]
findOut = [gname,city,company]
```

edit:
Try this

```
import java.util.Arrays;

public class Test {
    private static int indexOf(String[] array, String str) {
        for(int i = 0; i < array.length; i++) if(array[i].equals(str)) return i;
        return -1;
    }

    private static String toString(String[][] array) {
        String str = "";
        for(String[] sa: array) str += ", " + Arrays.toString(sa);
        return "[" + str.substring(2) + "]";
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String[][] arrayOne = {{"livesAt", "fname", "city"}, {"worksAt", "fname", "company"}};
        String[][] arrayTwo = {{"livesAt", "x", "y"}, {"worksAt", "x", "z"}};
        String[] findOut = {"x","y","z"};

        String[] newFindOut = findOut.clone();
        for(int y = 0; y < arrayTwo.length; y++) {
            for(int x = 0; x < arrayTwo[y].length; x++) {
                int i = indexOf(findOut, arrayTwo[y][x]);
                if(i >= 0) {
                    arrayTwo[y][x] = arrayOne[y][x];
                    newFindOut[i] = arrayOne[y][x];
                }
            }
        }
        findOut = newFindOut;

        System.out.println("arrayOne = " + toString(arrayOne));
        System.out.println("arrayTwo = " + toString(arrayTwo));
        System.out.println("findOut = " + Arrays.toString(findOut));
    }
}
```

Comment: Based on the code, it will have both `fname` and `gname`I think. The second `x` is found independent of first `x`

Comment: hi, the value of "x" can't have two different values (fname,gname). So, in arrayOne, it should have two fnames like the example I posted.

Answer (score 0):

Iterating through `arrayOne` is not required as we are comparing `arrayTwo` and `findOut`

Please note that as @SpiderPig pointed out this has `fname` `gname` problem (`findOut` values will be over written if `x` refers to two values in `arrayOne`) though `arrayTwo` values will be updated properly

```
public static void method(String[][] arrayOne, String[][] arrayTwo, String[] findOut)
{
    String[] findOutClone = findOut.clone();//Required for comparison, as we are mutating findOut
    for (int i = 0; i < arrayTwo.length; i++)
    {
        String[] arrTwo = arrayTwo[i];
        for (int j = 0; j < arrTwo.length; j++)
        {
            String arrTwoEl = arrTwo[j];
            for (int k = 0; k < findOutClone.length; k++)
                if (arrTwoEl.equals(findOutClone[k]))
                    arrTwo[j] = findOut[k] = arrayOne[i][j];
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, I think it's time for me to look up javadoc again.